# Jmeter vs LoadRunner in terms of vusers

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have found contradicting information, one saying JMeter can produce much more load then LR can, the other saying the opposite. From what I know (if we do not consider licencing), each LoadGenerator is only limited by hardware. But so is JMeter. The documentation did not help me much.
Does anyone have an experience with both of these so he can compare? I am speaking about 2 000- 4000 users.
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LoadRunner is known to run well with very high volume tests, as is, out of the box.

JMeter can typically hit issues with high throughput, high threaded tests in the following scenarios:

1. Using one machine, with lots of listeners, running in GUI mode - this eats memory.
2. Using distributed mode in default configuration with versions < 2.9 where there is not a problem to run the test on the Load Generator but there was a bottleneck sending results to the Master machine. This issue is reported to have been solved in 2.9 and throughput is claimed to be higher in 2.10.

The thing is, it's not that hard to solve JMeter's problems. It's simply a matter of best practice.

1. Run from the command line and don't use lots of listeners. Lean and Mean mode.
2. In distributed execution, use batch mode to reduce the volume of samples being written to one file in versions < 2.9 or use default configurations of >= 2.9.
3. Make sure you distribute the test over sufficient hardware. This is the same for LoadRunner by the way.

You should read those 2 documents for other best-practices:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

LoadRunner also has issues at high load - the Analysis and data collation phases can take hours (literally) and you can't get around this. If you have too much data to analyze you can also run into memory issues. Jmeter is not as comprehensive at results analysis but it is much quicker.

If you really need high volume tests then I wrote a [script](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) that effectively gives you infinite scalability with JMeter - I've tested it up to 20000 users making 8000 hits a second running over 50 servers. It's 'infinite' because it works by running lots of isolated tests that do not talk to each other until the end of the test, that way there is no bottleneck with compiling results. But there's always another bottleneck somewhere...

Comment: Regarding point 2. in the first paragraph, JMeter allows distributed testing?! I did not know that, I thought I would have to run other instances on other PCs.

Comment: Yes, JM uses RMI to run in master/slave mode. There's a document about it here. It's not as hard as that document makes it look but you should be aware that it will reach an io limit eventually, which is one of the reasons why I wrote that script.

Comment: If you need very large scale tests it's also possible to utilize JMeter in the cloud providers that utilize their own distributed JMeter technology and don't rely on JMeter's own internal master/slave.

Answer (score 3):

Both tools have track records at the level you note, 2-4K users.   Where the rubber meets the road is in terms of labor required to deliver test X at quality Y, including detailed analysis.   If you are investigating both tools then you should consider a POC on your app.

Document your script and your desired level of analysis independent of either tool and then hire an expert in both to run a POC against your requirements.   Time all of the tasks, even to the point of asking people to enter time at start of task and time at end of task in your documentation.   Compare both the times and the output at the end of the POC.

You should be aware that when you go to market to get an expert for either tool that the level of outright fraud in skills in the performance testing marketplace is on the order of 97% (or higher).   You want to hire someone with the strongest and longest track record with the tool under consideration with many references, otherwise you are likely to get a horribly distorted view of the capabilities and efficiencies of one or both tools which would likely lead to a poor decision on tool choice.

Expect to hire skills you may not have in house for either tool.  Many believe that the performance test tool represents 85-90% of the skills required for a performance testing job.   The inverse is actually true, with the tool skills running between 10-15% of the skills (critical skills) required to be successful.

Answer (score -8):

Jmeter is for poor schlubs.  Jmeter can only test a certain kinds of Java applications. It does not suppport ERP applications or web 2.0.  You can hook up Jmeter to ERP applications and try to record it. 6 weeks later Jmeter still will not work.

Comment: Could you please add more evidence or references?  I think the other answers have already covered a lot of ground, and see pros & cons to both tools.  Why are you so sure Jmeter is so bad?